# Product and Quotient Rule proof using linearisation

Tags: approximation, linear-approximation, linearization

So I've recently been introduced to the concept of linearization and now I'm beginning to apply this concept to prove certain differenation rules. I've managed to prove the chain rule so far, but I really can't think how to prove the product or quotient rule using linearization. Does anyone have any hints as to how to go about proving these rules? Will the proof of the chain rule come in handy?

Comment: So I've taken f(x)=g(x)h(x) and I've taken a linearisation of each part of the equation. From there, I don't really know where to go as there are no two parts that I can compare to find f'(x) unlike with the chain rule where I found two different expressions for f(x)

Answer (score 0):

Product rule:

Let
$$
f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0) + O(|x - x_0|^2)
$$
and
$$
g(x) = g(x_0) + g'(x_0)(x - x_0) + O(|x - x_0|^2).
$$
Then,
\begin{multline}
f(x)g(x) = \left[f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0) + O(|x - x_0|^2)\right] \cdot \\ \left[g(x_0) + g'(x_0)(x - x_0) + O(|x - x_0|^2)\right]
\end{multline}

So,
$$
f(x)g(x) = f(x_0) g(x_0) + \color{blue}{[f(x_0) g'(x_0) + f'(x_0) g(x_0)}](x - x_0) + O(|x - x_0|^2).
$$

Quotient rule can be proved as corollary, or you can do
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = a_0 + a_1 (x - x_0) + O(|x - x_0|^2),
$$
expand both $f$ and $g$, and determine the constants by equating the powers.

Comment: How can you prove the quotient rule from the corollary? I can't obviously see how to do it after from dividing by $g(x)^2$

Comment: You need the chain rule that you've already proved. If $g(x) = h^{-1}(x)$, then $g'(x) = -h'(x) h^{-2}(x)$.